# pygame window not opening via python launcher on mac

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))




running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

Comment: That's not the complete code, isn't it?

Comment: Hello, can you provide a maximum of details to explain your issue?

Comment: @totooooo the python launcher doesn't seem to respond when i run the program

Comment: Have you tried it in python REPL? This would help determine if the issue is python launcher

Comment: @totooooo ran the program in RELP but gives a error maeesage saying: " Repl.it: Package operation failed".

Comment: Hmm no that's not what I meant. A REPL broadly means an interface in which you can run your code interactively, iterating after each piece of your code ran. Repl.it seems to be a website that offers an online REPL, but I'm not surprised that pygame won't work in it. Can you open a terminal, type `python`, and try to run your script line by line? This is what I meant by REPL, although this was a bit unclear, sorry :)

Comment: works in terminal but not on the ide(pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

Go to bottom right of your Pycharm window,you should see Project interpreter,click interpreter settings,then double click pygames ,then click pygame in the list and check specify version box on the right,then select 2.0.0.dev6.Then click install package.Now it should work.